# Authentication with google account for native desktop app with backend

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, google-oauth

I have an application that has both a backend and a frontend (in java). I need to have user authentication but I would prefer not to handle most of it myself. So I thought I could have users authenticate with their google accounts.

The backend part is mostly implemented, and it works fine from the browser:

1. I try to navigate to a URL of my server, and the browser is redirected to the google login page.
2. I login, and the browser is redirected back to my server, this time with auth info (some kind of token?) and I get a response.

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to set this up from a desktop app. I would like for the app to have a login button that when pressed, opens the google login page in the system browser for the user to login. If the login is successful, the desktop client can use the info from their google account (e.g. the email address) to identify itself with my server.

It's the first time I'm working on something like this, so I don't know if I'm looking in the right place. My research online leads me to OAuth2.0, but that seems more like authorization than authentication.

I looked at google's [OpenID guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect) and it directed me to [using OAuth2 for installed applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#installed_applications), is that the right solution for my use case? Or is that for applications that only have a frontend and all data is kept in the desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure whether it is secure, and whether it aligns with best practices, but I found a solution. I used the idea of the [loopback redirect uri](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_loopback) in my own way.

1. I start an http listener on the desktop app on a random available port, let's say it's port 54321.
2. I want to contact a url to my server. In that url I add the loopback port as a query argument. So the url would be something like `https://myserver.org:8443/signin?loopback_port=54321`
3. I start the system browser with this url. The server requires authentication, so the browser is redirected to google to login and provide authorization for the application to access my google account data.
4. Once the login in google is done, the browser is redirected back to the url of my server that it was first trying to reach. Now since the authentication is done, the request goes through.
5. I updated the `/signin` endpoint on my server to return redirects to `/signin2` (again with the `loopback_port` param). The redirect from `/signin` will set the `JSESSIONID` in a cookie in the browser, and when we get the request in `/signin2`, we can read that `JSESSIONID`.
6. When we get the request in `/signin2`, we use the loopback port and the jsessionid to build a redirect url to the http listener on the desktop app. The jsessionid will be included as a query argument. So the browser is redirected to `http://localhost:54321/?JSESSIONID=...`.
7. The http listener on the desktop app parses the request to get the `JSESSIONID` from the cookie, and it can use that in subsequent requests it sends to the server. Having this cookie, the server associates the desktop app's request with the authentication done earlier.